# Linq query to order by on multiple related data

Tags: linq, entity-framework

Consider the below tables with the data

```
Customers -> Orders -> Items

Customers ->
A
B
C

Orders ->
o1 - A,
o2 - A,
o3 - B,
o4 - C

OrderItems ->
o1 - Item1,
o1 - Item2,
o2 - Item3,
o3 - Item2,
o4 - Item1

Item -> 
Item1,
Item2,
Item3,
Item4
```

We have a similar mapping as above in our DB.
Now in linq i would like to get List of Customers sorted by Items which are comma seperated
eg:

```
Customer     Items
C            Item1
A            Item1, Item2    
B            Item2
```

Ive tried something like this

```
Customer.OrderBy( cust => string.Join(",", cust.Orders
                                               .SelectMany( order=>order.OrderItems)
                                               .Select( orderItem=> orderItem.Item.Name)
                                               .OrderBy(item=>item)));
```

but string.Join is not allowed inside linq statements..
Its not required to display the Items in my grid, but i need to get customers sorted by the comma separated Items..

And also i dont want this to be done in the UI level as the sorting needs to be done on IQueryable customer object to which other filters are added and then executed later ..
A linq orderby query with IQueryable Customer object, returning an IQueryable object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are querying the Customer collection, your query will be converted to sql instructions. Since you mentioned other filters, I suppose it's a big table and you don't want to display / get all rows.

Even the string.Join operator were allowed in EF, your order clause operates on an complex statement that needs to be processed for each row to determine the correct result order (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string) for [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/545672/1020222) of what your string.join would do).

You need to somehow simplify your order clause or store the item list string into an sql field. If you can't store this string, you can try to create a stored procedure, a view or process the data using linq to objects (in this case, apply all filters using EF, get the results using .ToList() and apply your order filter using regular linq to objects).

Be aware that if you don't simplify your query and the customer table is big, [you'll face some performance issues](http://www.mythos-rini.com/blog/archives/4510).